"I'm not good at Korean"
The above sentence can be translated as "한국어 잘하지 못해요". But why not "한국어 잘할 수 없어요"? From what I understand, "못" implies that something is impossible to change, even with the subject's intervention, while "(으)ㄹ 수 없다" indicates a lack of will from the subject. But being good at Korean is something totally achievable, so why is "못" used?

한국어 잘 못해요. impossible to change "right now".

I don't think 못 imply "impossible to change". 못 implies "don't have ability to do something" here.

한국어 잘할 수 없어요 alone, a little awarkd. more context needed. 저는 언어 능력이 부족해서 한국어를 잘할 수 없어요. 저는 키가 작아서 농구 선수가 될 수 없어요.

"못" means that it is unable to do something represented by the verb, so "한국어 잘하지 못해요" means that the speaker is unable to speak Korean well.  This implies that, at the moment, the speaker lacks the ability to speak Korean well.
However, while having a similar meaning, "-(으)ㄹ 수 없다" carries a slightly different nuance.  The word "수" in the phrase represents a possibility for some event to happen.  Thus, "수 없다" indicates that something is not possible.  So, "한국어 잘할 수 없어요" means that the speaker has no possibility to speak Korean well.  This implies that, for some reason, it's not possible for the speaker to speak Korean well―perhaps due to lack of opportunity, environment, or any other external factor.
